# How do I write FileReader test in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, html, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to make this test work, but I couldn't get my head around how to write a test with FileReader. This is my code

```
function Uploader(file) {
    this.file = file;
}

Uploader.prototype =  (function() {

    function upload_file(file, file_contents) {
        var file_data = new FormData()
        file_data.append('filename', file.name)
        file_data.append('mimetype', file.type)
        file_data.append('data', file_contents)
        file_data.append('size', file.size)

        $.ajax({
            url: "/upload/file",
            type: "POST",
            data: file_contents,            
            contentType: file.type,
            success: function(){

                // $("#thumbnail").attr("src", "/upload/thumbnail");    

            },
            error: function(){
                alert("Failed");
            },
            xhr: function() {
                myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                if(myXhr.upload){
                    myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',showProgress, false);
                } else {
                    console.log("Upload progress is not supported.");
                }
                return myXhr;
            }
        });
    }

    return {
        upload : function() {
            var self = this,
                reader = new FileReader(),
                file_content = {};

            reader.onload = function(e) {
                file_content = e.target.result.split(',')[1];

                upload_file(self.file, file_content);
            }
        }
    };
})();
```

And this is my test

```
describe("Uploader", function() {
    it("should upload a file successfully", function() {
        spyOn($, "ajax");
        var fakeFile = {};

        var uploader = new Uploader(fakeFile);
        uploader.upload();

        expect($.ajax.mostRecentCall.args[0]["url"]).toEqual("/upload/file");
    })
});
```

But it never gets to `reader.onload`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem here is the use of `reader.onload` which is hard to test. You could use `reader.addEventListener` instead so you can spy on the global FileReader object and return a mock:

```
eventListener = jasmine.createSpy();
spyOn(window, "FileReader").andReturn({
 addEventListener: eventListener
})
```

then you can fire the onload callback by yourself:

```
expect(eventListener.mostRecentCall.args[0]).toEqual('load');
eventListener.mostRecentCall.args[1]({
  target:{
    result:'the result you wanna test'
  }
})
```

Comment: I'm stuck on this. Can anyone provide a working example? I'm always getting undefined (using Karma/Angular/Jasmine).

Comment: this is really outdated.

Comment: Nowadays I think it's better to not mock the FileReader at all, see my answer below.

Answer (score 15):

This syntax changed in 2.0. Code below gives an example based on Andreas Köberle's answer but using the new syntax

```
    // create a mock object, its a function with some inspection methods attached
    var eventListener = jasmine.createSpy();

    // this is going to be returned when FileReader is instantiated
    var dummyFileReader = { addEventListener: eventListener };

    // pipe the dummy FileReader to the application when FileReader is called on window
    // this works because window.FileReader() is equivalent to new FileReader()
    spyOn(window, "FileReader").and.returnValue(dummyFileReader)

    // your application will do something like this ..
    var reader = new FileReader();

    // .. and attach the onload event handler
    reader.addEventListener('load', function(e) {

        // obviously this wouldnt be in your app - but it demonstrates that this is the 
        // function called by the last line - onloadHandler(event);
        expect(e.target.result).toEqual('url');

        // jasmine async callback
        done();
    });

    // if addEventListener was called on the spy then mostRecent() will be an object. 
    // if not it will be null so careful with that. the args array contains the 
    // arguments that addEventListener was called with. in our case arg[0] is the event name ..
    expect(eventListener.calls.mostRecent().args[0]).toEqual('load');

    // .. and arg[1] is the event handler function
    var onloadHandler = eventListener.calls.mostRecent().args[1];

    // which means we can make a dummy event object .. 
    var event = { target : { result : 'url' } };

    // .. and call the applications event handler with our test data as if the user had 
    // chosen a file via the picker
    onloadHandler(event);
```

Comment: I found out that, strangely, if you create the FileReader implicitly on the global scope, like `new FileReader()`, jasmine can't find it, but if I call `new window.FileReader()` then the spy kicks in as expected. Cost me almost an hour to figure this out.

Answer (score 12):

I also faced similar problems and was able to achieve it without the use of `addeventlistener`. I had used `onloadend`, so below is what I did.

My TS file had the code below:

```
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function() {
                let dataUrl = reader.result;
                // Some working here
            };
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
```

My spec file (test) case code:

```
 let mockFileReader = {
            result:'',
            readAsDataURL:(blobInput)=> {
                console.log('readAsDataURL');
            },
            onloadend:()=> {
                console.log('onloadend');
            }
        };

    spyOn<any>(window, 'FileReader').and.returnValue(mockFileReader);
    spyOn<any>(mockFileReader, 'readAsDataURL').and.callFake((blobInput)=> {
        // debug your running application and assign to "encodedString" whatever 
        //value comes actually after using readAsDataURL for e.g. 
        //"data:*/*;base64,XoteIKsldk......"
        mockFileReader.result = encodedString;
        mockFileReader.onloadend();
    });
```

This way you have mocked the FileReader object and returned a fake call to your own `readAsDataURL`. And thus now when your actual code calls `reasAsDataURL` your fake function is called in which you are assigning an encoded string in `result` and calling the `onloadend` function which you had already assigned a functionality in your code (.ts) file. And hence it gets called with the expected result.

Answer (score 4):

I think the best way is to use the real `FileReader` (don't mock it), and pass in a real `File` or `Blob`. This improves your test coverage and makes your tests less brittle.

If your tests don't run in IE, you can use the [File constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File), e.g.

```js
const fakeFile = new File(["some contents"], "file.txt", {type: "text/plain"});
```

If you need to be compatible with IE, you can construct a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob) and make it look like a file:

```js
const fakeFile = new Blob(["some contents"]);
fakeFile.name = "file.txt";
fakeFile.type = "text/plain";
```

The `FileReader` can read either of these objects so there is no need to mock it.

Comment: I was struggling with this problem today, and your solution did make it much simpler. Thanks!

Comment: what if you want to test the `onerror` path? How would you do that?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible - you might need to use a mocking approach from one of the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

i found easiest for myself to do next.

- mock blob file
- run  *reader.onload* while in test environment.

as result -  i do not mock Filereader

```js
//    CONTROLLER

$scope.handleFile = function (e) {

            var f = e[0];

            $scope.myFile = {
                name: "",
                size: "",
                base64: ""
            };
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                        try {
                            var buffer = e.target.result;
                            $scope.myFile = {
                                name: f.name,
                                size: f.size,
                                base64: XLSX.arrayBufferToBase64(buffer)
                            };
                            $scope.$apply();

                        } catch (error) {
                            $scope.error = "ERROR!";
                            $scope.$apply();
                        }
                    };

reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
//run in test env
if ( typeof jasmine == 'object') {reader.onload(e)}
}

//JASMINE TEST

it('handleFile    0', function () {


    var  fileContentsEncodedInHex = ["\x45\x6e\x63\x6f\x64\x65\x49\x6e\x48\x65\x78\x42\x65\x63\x61\x75\x73\x65\x42\x69\x6e\x61\x72\x79\x46\x69\x6c\x65\x73\x43\x6f\x6e\x74\x61\x69\x6e\x55\x6e\x70\x72\x69\x6e\x74\x61\x62\x6c\x65\x43\x68\x61\x72\x61\x63\x74\x65\x72\x73"];
    var blob = new Blob(fileContentsEncodedInHex);
    blob.type = 'application/zip';
    blob.name = 'name';
    blob.size = 11111;
    var e = {0: blob, target: {result: {}}};

    $scope.handleFile(e);
    expect($scope.error ).toEqual("");

});
```

Comment: hm not a great idea to change code to make tests work

Answer (score 0):

I struggled to figure out how to test `onloadend` when it gets called from `readAsDataURL`.
Here is a dump of what I ended up with.

Production code:

```
loadFileDataIntoChargeback(tempFileList) {
        var fileNamesAndData = [];
        for (var i = 0, f; f = tempFileList[i]; i++) {
            let theFile = tempFileList[i];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = ((theFile) => {
                return (fileData) => {
                    var insertionIndex = this.chargeback.fileList.length;
                    this.chargeback.fileList.push({ FileName: theFile.name, Data: fileData.target.result, FileType: theFile.type });
                    this.loadFilePreviews(theFile, insertionIndex);
                }
            })(f);
            reader.readAsDataURL(f);
        }
        this.fileInputPath = "";
    }
```

Test code:

```
describe('when the files are loaded into the chargeback', () => {
            it('loads file previews', () => {
                let mockFileReader = {
                    target: { result: '' },
                    readAsDataURL: (blobInput) => {},
                    onloadend: () => {}
                };
                spyOn(chargeback, "loadFilePreviews");
                spyOn(window, 'FileReader').and.returnValue(mockFileReader);
                spyOn(mockFileReader, 'readAsDataURL').and.callFake((blobInput) => {
                    mockFileReader.onloadend({ target: { result: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QAYRXh" } });
                });
                var readFileList = chargeback.getArrayFromFileInput([getImageFile1()]);

                chargeback.loadFileDataIntoChargeback(readFileList);

                expect(chargeback.loadFilePreviews).toHaveBeenCalled();
            });
        });
```

Comment: @superITguy I'm afraid I don't remember. Sorry!