# How can I mock FileReader with jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, filereader

I've been struggling over the past couple of weeks with unit testing a file upload react component with jest. Specifically, I'm trying to test whether or not the method [onReadAsDataUrl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) is being called from FileReader in one of my methods. This is an example method I am testing:

```
loadFinalImage = async (file) => {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = () => {
    this.setState({
      imagePreviewUrl: reader.result,
      validCard: true,
    });
  };
  await reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

This is how I am attempting to mock FileReader and test whether or not onReadAsDataUrl has been called:

```
it('is a valid image and reader.onReadAsDataUrl was called', () => {
    const file = new Blob(['a'.repeat(1)], { type: 'image/png' });
    wrapper = shallow(<ImageUpload />).dive();
    const wrapperInstance = wrapper.instance();
    const mockReader = jest.fn();
    jest.spyOn('FileReader', () => jest.fn());
    FileReader.mockImplementation(() => { return mockReader });
    const onReadAsDataUrl = jest.spyOn(mockReader, 'readAsDataURL');
    wrapperInstance.loadFinalImage(file);
    expect(onReadAsDataUrl).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

After I run: `yarn jest`, I get the following test failure:

> Cannot spyOn on a primitive value; string given.

I assume I am getting this error because I am not importing `FileReader`, but I am not exactly sure how I would import it or mock it because `FileReader` is an interface. Here is an image of the test failure:
[image]

I am a bit of a noob with jest, reactjs, and web development, but would love to learn how to conquer this problem. Some resources I have looked at so far are: [Unresolved Shopify Mock of FileReader](https://github.com/Shopify/quilt/issues/303), [How to mock a new function in jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52859389/mock-new-function-with-jest), and [Mocking FileReader with jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15212348/how-do-i-write-filereader-test-in-jasmine).

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: According to the docs: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname, the function signature is: `jest.spyOn(object, methodName)`

Have you tried creating a mock for FileReader in the `global` and then doing `jest.spyOn(global, 'FileReader')` instead?

Comment: I swapped `jest.spyOn('FileReader', () => jest.fn())` for `jest.spyOn(global, 'FileReader')` and the error message changed to this line: `FileReader.mockImplementation(() => { return mockReader })`. The new error message is: `TypeError: _sys.default.mockImplementation is not a function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally could not get any of the jest.spyOn() approaches to work.

Using `jest.spyOn(FileReader.prototype, 'readAsDataURL')` kept generating a `Cannot spy the readAsDataURL property because it is not a function; undefined given instead` error,

and `jest.spyOn(global, "FileReader").mockImplementation(...)` returned a `Cannot spy the FileReader property because it is not a function; undefined given instead` error

I managed to successfully mock the FileReader prototype using the following:

```
Object.defineProperty(global, 'FileReader', {
  writable: true,
  value: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    readAsDataURL: jest.fn(),
    onLoad: jest.fn()
  })),
})
```

Then in my test, I was able to test the file input onChange method (which was making use of the FileReader) by mocking the event and triggering it manually like this:

```
const file = {
  size: 1000,
  type: "audio/mp3",
  name: "my-file.mp3"
}
const event = {
  target: {
    files: [file]
  }
}
wrapper.vm.onChange(event)
```

I hope it can help anyone else looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

Quite possibly the OP has found an answer by now, but since I was facing pretty much the same problem, here's how I did it - taking input from [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61575553/222529).

I think @Jackyef comment is the right way to go, but I don't think the call to `mockImplementation` you propose is correct.

In my case, the following turned out to be correct.

```
const readAsDataURL = jest
  .spyOn(global, "FileReader")
  .mockImplementation(function() {
    this.readAsDataURL = jest.fn();
  });
```

Worth noting that VSCode highlights a potential refactoring at the anonymous function. It suggests:

```
class (Anonymous function)
(local function)(): void
This constructor function may be converted to a class declaration.ts(80002)
```

I'm still relatively new to JS, so I'm afraid I can't explain what this is about, nor what refactoring should be done.