# How to test FileReader onload using simulate change in jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

SimpleDialog.jsx

```
const [imagePreview, setImagePreview] = React.useState(null);

const handleChangeImage = event => {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    let file = event.target.files[0];

    reader.onload = event => {
        console.log(event);

        setImagePreview(event.target.result);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
};

return (
    <div>
        <input
            accept="image/*"
            id="contained-button-file"
            multiple
            type="file"
            style={{ display: 'none' }}
            onChange={handleChangeImage}
        />

        <img id="preview" src={imagePreview} />
    </div>
);
```

SimpleDialog.test.js

```
it('should change image src', () => {
    const event = {
        target: {
            files: [
                {
                    name: 'image.png',
                    size: 50000,
                    type: 'image/png'
                }
            ]
        }
    };

    let spy = jest
        .spyOn(FileReader.prototype, 'onload')
        .mockImplementation(() => null);

    wrapper.find('input[type="file"]').simulate('change', event);

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();

    expect(wrapper.find('#preview').prop('src')).not.toBeNull();
});
```

When running the test it gives me the error *TypeError: Illegal invocation*.

Anyone who can help me with this unit test? I Just want to simulate on change if the *src* of an image has value or not.

Comment: I would recommend that you use [URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) instead. but just don't forget to [revoke](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL) it when you no longer need it any longer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cause of the error is that `onload` is defined as property descriptor and assigning it to `FileReader.prototype` which is done by `spyOn` isn't supported.

There's no reason to mock `onload` because it's assigned in tested code and needs to be tested.

The straightforward way is to not patch JSDOM `FileReader` implementation but stub it entirely:

```
jest.spyOn(global, 'FileReader').mockImplementation(function () {
    this.readAsDataURL = jest.fn();
});

wrapper.find('input[type="file"]').simulate('change', event);


let reader = FileReader.mock.instances[0];
expect(reader.readAsDataURL).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...);
expect(reader.onload).toBe(expect.any(Function));

expect(wrapper.find('#preview').prop('src')).toBeNull();

reader.onload({ target: { result: 'foo' } });

expect(wrapper.find('#preview').prop('src')).toBe('foo');
```

Comment: Thank you @Estus Flask. I'm a bit confused regarding the `onload` event. So all methods and events here were mocked? Can you give me a reference?

Comment: onload is just listener for `load` event that is triggered by FileReader, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload . Here it's tested that a listener was set by the component and that it produces necessary side effects.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with checking some side effect that should be invoked on FileReader.onload, so I just ended up setting a short pause after triggering the event (I'm using enzyme + jest). Setting the timeout is probably not the best solution here, but it was the only thing that worked.

```
const pauseFor = milliseconds => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));
...
wrapper.find('.upload-box').simulate('drop', someMockedDropEvent);
// set pause was the only way to make reader.onload to fire
await pauseFor(100);
expect(something).toEqual(something)
```