# How to write unit test for code inside onloadend?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

My function in file user-profile.component.ts:

```
    loadImage(file) {
      const myReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
      myReader.onloadend = () => {
        this.imageInBase64 = myReader.result;
      };
      myReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
```

and user-profile.component.spec.ts

```
    it('upload image success', async () => {
      const file = new File([new Blob(['123'])], 'abc.png', { type: 'image/png' });

      component.loadImage(file);

      expect(component.imageInBase64.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    });
```

I always get "Expected 0 to be greater than 0". How to write a right unit test for this case?

I tried mockFileReader from [How do I write FileReader test in Jasmine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15212348/how-do-i-write-filereader-test-in-jasmine) but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test runs before the image is loaded. The image is loaded on the `load` event but your `loadImage` function returns before the event is fired.

You can solve this by returning a Promise from `loadImage`:

```
    loadImage(file) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const myReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
        myReader.onloadend = () => {
          this.imageInBase64 = myReader.result;
          resolve();
        };
        myReader.readAsDataURL(file);
      });
    }
```

And then await for `loadImage` in your test:

```
    it('upload image success', async () => {
      const file = new File([new Blob(['123'])], 'abc.png', { type: 'image/png' });

      await component.loadImage(file);

      expect(component.imageInBase64.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    });
```

You probably also need to add some error handling and call `reject` when an error occurs. Also, you could return `myReader.result` from the Promise, instead of using a member variable.