# how "component.QRcode" will be defined in the spec.test file

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

> .ts file

```
generateQRCode(data){
     let reader = new FileReader();
     reader.readAsDataURL(data);
     reader.onload = ()=>{
       this.QRcode = reader.result;
     }
   }
```

> .spec.ts file

```
it('generateQRCode',()=>{
     const fakeFile = new File([new Blob(['123'])], 'abc.gif',{type:'image/gif'})
     component.generateQRCode(fakeFile)
     **expect(component.QRcode).toBeDefined();**
   })
```

> how to "component.QRcode" will be defined in the test file

Comment: Check out NVCoder's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15212348/how-do-i-write-filereader-test-in-jasmine